# Find file path from a named import in ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to obtain the file where a named import is loaded in ES6. Let's say i have

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const dummy = () => (
   <div>
      Hello!
   </div>


);

export default dummy;
```

I'm processing this file and trying to find out from which file the Component import is loaded. As far as i research, i can use `require.resolve()`, but it only tells me the index file from a module. What i want to know is from which file a named import is loaded... Any idea?

Comment: It was loaded from the index file.

Comment: Yes, what i want to know is from which file that is included in the index that import comes from. generally they are not defined in the index, the come as a require form another file.

Comment: It would not be easy - you need a proper JS parser for that.